# Final clause in C switch statement (possibly using goto)

Tags: c, switch-statement, goto

I could use something like javas finally clause in a C switch. Most of my cases has a shared set of functionality that I would like to put a single case. I was thinking of implementing this using goto statements, being well aware of gotos code obfuscation ability, putting the shared case at the bottom of the switch statement still seems a "cleaner" way to do this than partitioning the shared functionality into a seperate function.

Anyway, I have been trying to do it something like this:

```
switch( x ) {
case 0:
    printf("Case 0\n");
    goto case 2;
    break;
case 1:
    printf("Case 1\n");
    goto case 2;
    break;
case 2:
    printf("Case 2\n");
    break;
default:
    // do nothing
    break;
}
```

However, using gcc, this fail with the error

```
error: expected identifier or ‘*’ before ‘case’
```

Any suggestions on how to make it work? Or possibly a better approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "best practice" is of course to delegate the shared code to a function. But in some situations where this is overengineering, or simply not possible / desirable, then you can do:

```
switch( x ) 
{
case 0:
    printf("Case 0\n");
    goto shared_material;

case 1:
    printf("Case 1\n");
    goto shared_material; // Unnecessary, but keep it for clarity.

case 2:
shared_material:
    printf("Case 2\n");
    break;

default:
    // Write a meaningful error message somewhere
    return -1;
}
```

I don't find this too unreadable, and I don't have any problem with it, **provided the whole statement fits in one screen** (otherwise it qualifies as *spaghetti code*). However, you may have to defend it in code reviews, which is one of the main reasons I would step away from such constructs and rethink the code.

Comment: Well, this works. I just sorta thought that the case statements were labels internally in the switch statements.

Comment: @Kenneth: not in C. They are in C# (and possibly in Java), because C# doesn't allow you to fall through a `case` statement, so you use `goto` where in C you would use a `// fall through` comment.

Comment: Internally, in the generated code, they behave like labels, but in C, syntactically, they are not.

Comment: I agree with this solution and your comment as well! If the shared code is of significant size it deserves its own function. In my case the total shared code is four lines (using two local variables) and adding a function just seems... well what's the opposite of cluttered code, scattered code?

Comment: "....But in some situations where this is overengineering, or simply not possible / desirable"... I challenge you to exhibit "some situations".

Comment: @Karl: overengineering: when the cleanup code is two lines long, and involves several local variables. not desirable: when profiling shows that the extra function call hurts performance. Also, see my comment to Johan's answer: there are code duplication issues if you use a cleanup function. As long as the whole switch statement fits in one screen (so that you can see at a glance what the instruction flow is), this approach is OK.

Answer (score 3):

Why not put the common code *after* the switch?

I feel I have to update this reply, paraphrasing the accepted answer with one I feel has a better design:

```
switch( x )
{
    case 0:
        printf("Case 0\n");
        break;

    case 1:
        printf("Case 1\n");
        break;

    case 2:
        break;

    default:
        return -1; 
}

printf("Common code for cases 0, 1 and 2\n");
```

Or, you could of course set a flag in the 'default' case that would prevent the common code from executing, if you for some reason don't want to break it out to a separate function.

Comment: I forgot to mention that only some cases needs to share that code.

Comment: Then it's not working like javas' _finally_ ;-) Updated my answer too to show what I mean

Comment: True. And finally only applies to exceptions as well. Maybe a should rephrase the original question.

Comment: ...actually not, see the tutorial for Java finally ;-) (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html )

Answer (score 2):

you could use a flag `do2`, set it if needed and check it after the switch.

if it is more complex with many hierarchical dependencies then build a state machine with transitions.

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather going for this approach:

```
void sharedFunction() {
    printf("Case 2\n");
}

switch( x ) {
case 0:
    printf("Case 0\n");
    sharedFunction();
    break;
case 1:
    printf("Case 1\n");
    sharedFunction();
    break;
case 2:
    sharedFunction();
    break;
default:
    // do nothing
    break;
}
```

Comment: I know that this is the "right way" to do it, but that seems cluttered to me, as the shared code in this case are no more than a handful of lines.

Comment: There's no limit how short a function might be. :)

Comment: @Kenneth: I don't like it either. When you want to add shared stuff which depends on local variables, then you'll have to add an argument to `sharedFunction` and thus to change the code in 3 different places. The `goto` approach is superior in this respect. Clean solutions should stay away from the `switch` construct insofar as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Following works:

```
switch( x ) {
case 0:
    printf("Case 0\n");
    if(0)
case 1:{
    printf("Case 1\n");
    }
case 2:
    printf("Case 2\n");
    break;
default:
    // do nothing
    break;
}
```

Comment: I am impressed. I would never have come up with this and I would hate to maintain code that included this, but I am impressed none the less.

Comment: @Kenneth, wrapping all `case` statements in `{}` is a good practice (here you should wrap all of them in `{}`). What I am doing is just putting an `if(0)`. At least avoiding the use of `goto`.

Comment: But this solution will only work for a single case statement.

Comment: @Kenneth, it will work universally; I have written here what you posted in your question. You can extend as you want.